# footnotemark positioning

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

I use in my manuscript code to set the footnote marks in a special way. All footnote marks are set left aligned. Except on pages, where the footnote marks have different digits. On such a page, the very right digit of the largest footnote gives the position for all the others.

The code is from @cabohah and is posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676399/footnote-editing-with-koma-script/676909#676909)

Everything works very well. After two runs of compilation everything is fine. The position of every footnote with 1, 2 or even 3 digits is as I need it.

But I found one example, when the code fails and write a corrupt footnote–page–relation to the `aux` file. `\setcounter{footnote}{4}` delivers a wrong positioning of footnote mark 5–9, starting the footnote counter with 3 or 5 results in a correct positioning.

Is there any help to get this debugged??

```latex
\documentclass[pagesize,parskip=half,DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% shouldn't be needed any longer
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent 7mm% Really, paragraph skip _and_ indent???

\newlength{\myfnindent}
\newlength{\myfnnumwidth}
\deffootnote{\myfnindent}{\myfnindent}{% indent of footnote text and paragraphs
  \makebox[\myfnindent][l]{% inside this indent left align a 
    \makebox[\myfnnumwidth][r]{% box of per page number width with right aligned
      \thefootnotemark% bold footnote mark
      % HJELE \bfseries\thefootnotemark% bold footnote mark
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{footnote/text/begin}{%
  \settowidth{\myfnnumwidth}{\footnotesize\thefootnotemark}% width of current footnote mark
  % HJELE \settowidth{\myfnnumwidth}{\footnotesize\bfseries\thefootnotemark}% width of current footnote mark
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{fnnumwidth@\thepage}{\the\myfnnumwidth}}% write it as current widest per page mark width to aux-file
  \@ifundefined{fnnumwidth@\thepage}{}{% if the aux file has had per page values for this page
    \setlength{\myfnnumwidth}{\@nameuse{fnnumwidth@\thepage}}% use (the last one) as current width of the number bix
  }%
  \@gobble% Because the do-hook code expects always has an argument.
}
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{% becaue font initialization usually happens at \begin{document}
  % HJELE \settowidth{\myfnindent}{\footnotesize\bfseries 888\enskip}% In this example
  \settowidth{\myfnindent}{\footnotesize 888\enskip}% In this example
                                % 888 is the widest used number and this is
                                % used to setup the footnote text indent.
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

% HJELE: set this value to 3 or 5, everything is fine
% HJELE: set this value to 4, the positioning of the
%        footnotemarks is just on this page incorrect
%        --> see the aux file for the wrong page--footnote--relation
\setcounter{footnote}{5}
Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

A one digit bigger footnotemark.\footnote{huhu}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: correct positioning]
[image: incorrect positioning]

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with moving footnotes in this nonsensical requirement. For example, with maybe one more LaTeX run, because of one label per footnote, this can be solved:

```
\documentclass[pagesize,% Option is already the default. So you can remove it.
  parskip=half,DIV=11]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% shouldn't be needed any longer
\usepackage[german]{babel}% Do you really use the old German spelling from the
                          % last century???
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}
\parindent 7mm% BAD CODE! See the KOMA-Script manual how to change paragraph
              % indent and paragraph skip. But using both is not recommended!

\newlength{\myfnindent}
\newlength{\myfnnumwidth}
\deffootnote{\myfnindent}{\myfnindent}{% indent of footnote text and paragraphs
  \makebox[\myfnindent][l]{% inside this indent left align a 
    \makebox[\myfnnumwidth][r]{% box of per page number width with right aligned
      \thefootnotemark% bold footnote mark
      % HJELE \bfseries\thefootnotemark% bold footnote mark
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\AddtoDoHook{footnote/text/begin}{%
  \settowidth{\myfnnumwidth}{\footnotesize\thefootnotemark}% width of current footnote mark
  % HJELE \settowidth{\myfnnumwidth}{\footnotesize\bfseries\thefootnotemark}%
  % width of current footnote mark
  \label{ftn:\thefootnotemark}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\global\noexpand\@namedef{fnnumwidth@\getpagerefnumber{ftn:\thefootnotemark}}{\the\myfnnumwidth}}% write it as current widest per page mark width to aux-file
  \@ifundefined{fnnumwidth@\getpagerefnumber{ftn:\thefootnotemark}}{}{% if the aux file has had per page values for this page
    \setlength{\myfnnumwidth}{\@nameuse{fnnumwidth@\getpagerefnumber{ftn:\thefootnotemark}}}% use (the last one) as current width of the number bix
  }%
  \@gobble% Because the do-hook code expects always has an argument.
}
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{% becaue font initialization usually happens at \begin{document}
  % HJELE \settowidth{\myfnindent}{\footnotesize\bfseries 888\enskip}% In this example
  \settowidth{\myfnindent}{\footnotesize 888\enskip}% In this example
                                % 888 is the widest used number and this is
                                % used to setup the footnote text indent.
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

% HJELE: set this value to 3 or 5, everything is fine
% HJELE: set this value to 4, the positioning of the
%        footnotemarks is just on this page incorrect
%        --> see the aux file for the wrong page--footnote--relation
\setcounter{footnote}{4}
Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

Very small footnotemark.\footnote{\blindtext}

A one digit bigger footnotemark.\footnote{huhu}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Note: I do not recommend such strange formatting of footnotes. So I will not spend more time for it.

Comment: I know this is sort of strange. But it's in this case not up to me how to set the footnotemarks. Historically many works where set in this way. Thx for your help and the comments. Harald